# Converting map having WMS layers to an image and use it in PDF, but it's working for WFS layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using this method to convert the Map containing WMS layer to an image, and later use that image in a PDF. Everything is working fine for WFS layers, but not with WMS layers.

```js
function CaptureImage() {
    map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        var canvas = event.context.canvas;
        console.log(canvas);

        if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png');

        } else {
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                var imgData = new Image();
                imgData = canvas.toDataURL("png");

                // Later I'm saving this image, but this is working for WFS, but not WMS Layers ;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What version of ol are you using? In the newer versions, the map fires a 'postrender'-event, which is made exactly for this task.

Comment: I'm using ol version 4.6.5

Comment: yes i think that didn't exist back then... if you don't want to update, can you try to add a setTimeout inside your function, just to make sure that this is indeed the problem?

Comment: @Rob can I get the code if you have it, just the relevant one. Thank you Rob

Comment: right after your line 'map.once('postcompose'...
write:  
setTimeout(function(){  XXXXXX  }, 10000);    and replace the XXXXXX with your code of your example. This will wait 10 seconds until the png is created. Remember, this is just a quick try to figure out the problem, not suited for production.